# Convert yyyyMMdd to date time in linq select

Tags: c#, .net, linq, type-conversion

Is it a way to convert a string of `yyyyMMdd` to date time in linq select.

1 - I try `Convert.toDateTime(), DateTime.ParseExact(), DateTime.Parse()`. All of them give me error.

Error Message are similar to this.

Additional information: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.DateTime Parse(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

2 - I can be sure those data need to convert to date validate date with `yyyyMMdd` format.

Please see my following code to understand what exactly do i mean.

```
return (from p in db.ExchangeDatas
            where p.ExchangeDataSeqid == entity.ExchangeDataSeqid
            select new ProcessAccountViewModel()
            {
                ExchangeCode = p.ExchangeCode,
                UtilityCompany = p.UtilityCompanySeqid,
                InvoiceBillingGroup = p.AccountBillingGroupSeqid,
                AccountNumber = p.CurrentAccountNumber,
                TurnOnDate = DateTime.ParseExact(p.AccountEffectiveTurnOn, "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
                SalesType = p.SalesType,
                BillingCycle = p.BillingCycle,
                TripNumber = p.TripNumber,
                IsTimeOfDay = p.TODAccount == "Y" ? true : false,
                IsExcessDistribution = p.ExcessDistributionAccount == "Y" ? true : false,
                EnergyDeliverType = p.EnergyDeliveryType ?? 0,
                Name = p.AccountName,
                Address = p.AccountAddress,
                Borough = p.Borough,
                Facility = p.FacilitySeqid == null ? "" : p.FacilitySeqid.Value.ToString(),
                Agency = p.AgencySeqid == null ? "" : p.AgencySeqid.Value.ToString(),
                ServiceClass = p.DeliveryServiceClass,
                AuthenticatedUserID = p.authenticatedUserID ?? 0,
                ApprovedForCreation = p.ApprovedForCreation,
                TransactionEffectiveDate = DateTime.ParseExact(p.TransactionEffectiveDate, "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
                ActivityTime = DateTime.ParseExact(p.ActivityTime, "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
                DateAdded = p.DateAdded,
                LastUpdate = p.LastUpdate,
                Exclude = p.Exclude,
                IsProcessed = p.IsProcessed,
                BillingPeriod = p.BillingPeriod
            }).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: You need to format the date after execution, LINQ cannot convert `ParseExact` to SQL because there is no equivalent function

Comment: In the class ProcessAccountViewModel are they defined as DateTime properties?

Comment: @jdweng yes they are.

Comment: The only time I have issues with code like yours is when the times are null.  In those cases I use  p.ActivityTime == null ? new DateTime() : DateTime.ParseExact(p.ActivityTime, "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)

Comment: To further explain @DGibbs comment: This is an EF issue, not a LINQ issue. Remember the nature of EF an Queryables. They a lazy executed so at the time the lamda's are used, linq figures out its provider, notices its EF and then asks the EF query provider to translate all the statements into SQL. The EF query provider doesn't know how to map DateTime.ParseExact so it errors. So, you need to return the full set by calling ToList and then select from that. Again, linq relies on its query providers whether LinqToEntites, or LinqToObjects, or others.

Comment: Good explanation @ManOVision, but please do not recommend people to use `.ToList()` for something like this. You could use `.AsEnumerable()` if you want to further process the results with linq to objects.

Comment: I could not get DateTime.Parse() or DateTime.ParseExact() to work without getting "Method 'System.DateTime Parse(System.String)' has no supported translation to SQL."  Convert.ToDateTime() worked for me.  Are you sure your data is in yyyyMMdd? Maybe you are getting past the "no supported translation" and getting into more of an out of range exception? I feel your pain but again, Convert.ToDateTime() is currently working for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LINQ to enitites does not support DateTime.ParseExact method so you can try to bring the collection you need into memory by using AsEnumerable(), and then do all the parsing using LINQ to Objects.

maybe this will work?

```
var exchangeDatas = from p in db.ExchangeDatas
                    where p.ExchangeDataSeqid == entity.ExchangeDataSeqid
                    select p;

return (from p in exchangeDatas.AsEnumerable() 
                  select new ProcessAccountViewModel()
                  {
                      ExchangeCode = p.ExchangeCode,
                      UtilityCompany = p.UtilityCompanySeqid,
                      InvoiceBillingGroup = p.AccountBillingGroupSeqid,
                      AccountNumber = p.CurrentAccountNumber,
                      TurnOnDate = DateTime.ParseExact(p.AccountEffectiveTurnOn, "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
                      SalesType = p.SalesType,
                      BillingCycle = p.BillingCycle,
                      TripNumber = p.TripNumber,
                      IsTimeOfDay = p.TODAccount == "Y" ? true : false,
                      IsExcessDistribution = p.ExcessDistributionAccount == "Y" ? true : false,
                      EnergyDeliverType = p.EnergyDeliveryType ?? 0,
                      Name = p.AccountName,
                      Address = p.AccountAddress,
                      Borough = p.Borough,
                      Facility = p.FacilitySeqid == null ? "" : p.FacilitySeqid.Value.ToString(),
                      Agency = p.AgencySeqid == null ? "" : p.AgencySeqid.Value.ToString(),
                      ServiceClass = p.DeliveryServiceClass,
                     AuthenticatedUserID = p.authenticatedUserID ?? 0,
                     ApprovedForCreation = p.ApprovedForCreation,
                     TransactionEffectiveDate = DateTime.ParseExact(p.TransactionEffectiveDate, "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
                     ActivityTime = DateTime.ParseExact(p.ActivityTime, "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
                     DateAdded = p.DateAdded,
                     LastUpdate = p.LastUpdate,
                     Exclude = p.Exclude,
                     IsProcessed = p.IsProcessed,
                     BillingPeriod = p.BillingPeriod
                 }).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this will work, but try adding some logic in your `ProcessAccountViewModel` to handle that for you.  Something like this:

```
class ProcessAccountViewModel()
{
   ...
   DateTime TransactionEffectiveDate { get; set; } // you already have this
   string TransactionEffectiveDateAsString // add this
   {
       set
       {
           TransactionEffectiveDate = DateTime.ParseExact(value,
                      "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
       }
   }
}
```

Then, instead of setting TransactionEffectiveDate directly in your LINQ query, use the string version:

So, instead of:

```
TransactionEffectiveDate = DateTime.ParseExact(p.TransactionEffectiveDate,
                                "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
```

Do

```
TransactionEffectiveDateAsString = p.TransactionEffectiveDate,
```